# How to integrate with anyswap router

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

I need to create my own token router form integrating with anyswap router https://anyswap.exchange/bridge#/router

I am creating an instance of a contract based on it's ABI and then I am calling this method of the instance anySwapOutUnderlying

```
const myContract = web3.eth.Contract(routerAbi, '0xf390830df829cf22c53c8840554b98eafc5dcbc2')
const contractData = myContract.methods.anySwapOutUnderlying(
 '0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955',
 '0x382bb369d343125bfb2117af9c149795c6c65c50',
 1,
 137,
).encodeABI()
```

then I am preparing the request data:

```
const requestData = {
 chainId: web3.utils.toHex(56),
 from: 'my cool address',
 gas: '',
 gasPrice: '',
 nonce: '',
 to: '0x382bb369d343125bfb2117af9c149795c6c65c50',
 value: '0x0',
 data: contractData,
}
```

afterwards I am creating a batch where I add a couple of steps, but nothing happens at the end once I execute it

Comment: you can't do it, it has to be done by Anyswap itself https://docs.multichain.org/for-partners/erc20-token/cross-chain-options

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa thank you for your reply, but I just need to implement a functionality which let me transfer my USDT and other stable coins from BSC to Polygon and that's it